# A 3 dimensional array represented by a 2 dimensional array-

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, 3d, textures, webgl

So in WebGL, I can store a texture in up to 2 dimensions- and read it in the shader using texture2D(whatever);

If i wanted to store a 3 dimensional texture so that I can read 3-dimensions worth of data on the shader, how would I do it?

Here are my ideas- and I am wondering if I am approaching it correctly:

In Javascript:

```
var info = [];

for (var x = 0; x < 1; x+=.1) {
     for (var y = 0; y < 1; y+=.1) {
          for (var z = 0; z < 1; z+=.1) {

               info.push (x*y*z); 
               info.push(0);
               info.push(0);
               info.push(0);

          }
     }
}

//bind texture here- whatever

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 10, 100, 0,
                  gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, data_on_shader);

//other texture stuff
```

On the shader:

```
uniform sampler data_on_shader;
x= texture.r//
y = texture.g//
z = texture.b//

xfixed = floor(x*10.)/10. + .5;
yfixed = floor(y*10.)/10. + .5;
zfixed = floor(z*10.)/10. + .5;

float data_received = texture2D(data_on_shader, vec2(xfixed, yfixed*10. + zfixed)).r;
```

Something to the effect of using row major order within a 2d texture?
Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You can simulate a 3d texture by storing each plane of the 3d texture in a 2d texture

Then a function like this will let you use it as a 3d texture

```
vec4 sampleAs3DTexture(sampler2D tex, vec3 texCoord, float size) {
    float sliceSize = 1.0 / size;                         // space of 1 slice
    float slicePixelSize = sliceSize / size;              // space of 1 pixel
    float sliceInnerSize = slicePixelSize * (size - 1.0); // space of size pixels
    float zSlice0 = min(floor(texCoord.z * size), size - 1.0);
    float zSlice1 = min(zSlice0 + 1.0, size - 1.0);
    float xOffset = slicePixelSize * 0.5 + texCoord.x * sliceInnerSize;
    float s0 = xOffset + (zSlice0 * sliceSize);
    float s1 = xOffset + (zSlice1 * sliceSize);
    vec4 slice0Color = texture2D(tex, vec2(s0, texCoord.y));
    vec4 slice1Color = texture2D(tex, vec2(s1, texCoord.y));
    float zOffset = mod(texCoord.z * size, 1.0);
    return mix(slice0Color, slice1Color, zOffset);
 }
```

If your 3d texture was 8x8x8 then you'd make a 2d texture that is 64x8 and put each plane of the 3d texture in your 2d texture. Then, knowing that was originally 8x8x8 you'd pass in `8.0` for the size to `sampleAs3DTexture`

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_my3DTexture;
varying vec3 v_texCoord;

...

#define CUBE_SIZE 8.0

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = sampleAs3DTexture(u_my3DTexture, v_texCoord, CUBE_SIZE);
}
```

Note: the function above assumes you want bilinear filtering between the planes. If you don't you can simplify the function.

There's [a video explanation of this code here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfQ8rKGTVlg#t=26m00s) which is from [this sample](http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/color-adjust/color-adjust.html).