# Create a 2D texture from existing textures

Tags: three.js, texture-atlas

I have an application where I load a series of medical images (jpg), create a texture object for each image and display those textures on 3D planes. The amount of images depends in the CT scanner's resolution but my prototype should work with up to 512.

As an additional task, I want to use those textures to perform volumetric rendering on a separate 3D canvas.

All the algorithms that tackle the lack of 3D textures in WebGL have as a "silent" prerequisite that a texture atlas in an image format already exists.

In my case however I don't have such an atlas.

1. Assuming that the hardware supports the resulting size of this 2D texture-atlas, how could I tailor the already loaded textures into one single 2D texture and feed it to the shader?
2. I thought about merging the data of each image into a single array and with it create THREE.DataTexture. But I couldn't find a way to read the image's data from the texture that uses it. Is there some another way to extract the data of the loaded image?

Comment: actually you don't have to create a 2D atlas but you can simulate the existence of a 3D texture. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939557/a-3-dimensional-array-represented-by-a-2-dimensional-array and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfQ8rKGTVlg#t=25m03s

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peter O. However what you describe is the next step in my process. It assumes that I have loaded the array with all images in the sampler2D tex. What I am asking, is how to do that, given the conditions of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to load your textures into a 2d canvas to build your atlas.

Let's assume we have a function that downloads 512 textures and we want to put them in a grid of 32 by 16

```
var width = 128;  // just assuming this is the size of a single texture
var height = 128; 
var across = 32;
var down = 16;

asyncLoad512Images(useLoaded512Images);

function useLoaded512Images(arrayOfImages) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = width * across;
  canvas.height = height * down;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // draw all the textures into the canvas
  arrayOfImagess.forEach(function(image, ndx) {
    var x = ndx % across;
    var y = Math.floor(ndx / across);

    ctx.drawImage(image, x * width, y * height);
  }

  // now make a texture from canvas.
  var atlasTex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, atlasTex);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                canvas);
}
```

Some optimizations: You might change the code so you make the canvas at the beginning and as each image loads draw it into the 2d canvas at the correct place. The advantage will be that the browser won't need to keep all 512 images in memory. It can discard each one right after you've drawn it.

```
var width = 128;  // just assuming this is the size of a single texture
var height = 128; 
var across = 32;
var down = 16;
var numImages = 32 * 16;
var numImagesDownloaded = 0;

// make a canvas to hold all the slices
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = width * across;
canvas.height = height * down;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// assume the images are named image-x.png
for (var ii = 0; ii < numImages; ++ii) {
  loadImage(ii);
}

function loadImage(num) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = putImageInCanvas(img, num);
  img.src = "image-" + num + ".png";
}

function putImageInCanvas(img, num) {
  var x = num % across;
  var y = Math.floor(num / across);

  ctx.drawImage(img, x * width, y * height);

  ++numImagesDownloaded;
  if (numImagesDownloaded === numImages) {
    // now make a texture from canvas.
    var atlasTex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, atlasTex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  canvas);
    ....
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can turn each image into a texture and use a texture attached to a framebuffer to render the image texture into the atlas texture. That's more work. You need to make a simple 2d pair of shaders and then render each image texture to the atlas texture at the correct place.

The only reason to do that off the top of my head is if the textures have 4 channels of data instead of 3 or less as there's no way to use all 4 channels with the 2d canvas since 2d canvas always uses premultiplied alpha.

Drawing a texture into a texture is the same as drawing period. [See any example that draws into a texture](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_rtt.html).

The short version in three.js is,

make a render target

```
rtTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( 
      width * across, height * down, { 
        minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, 
        magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, 
        format: THREE.RGBFormat,
        depthBuffer: false,
        stencilBuffer: false,
    } ); 
 rtTexture.generateMipmaps = false;
```

Set up a plane and a material to render with, put it in a scene. For each image texture set the material to use that image texture and setup whatever other parameters to make it draw the quad where you want it to be drawn into the atlas texture. [I'm guessing an orthographic camera would make that easiest](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html). Then call render with the render target.

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
renderer.render( sceneRTT, cameraRTT, rtTexture, false );
```

That will render to `rtTexture`.

When you're done `rtTexture` is your atlas texture. Just use the texture like any texture. Assign it to a material.

Comment: Thank for your reply you gman. The first approach seems to fit better since I use the build in Three.js  functions to load the images onto the textures.
The memory usage is no problem (for the time being at least). My main concern is the speed. 
I say that because I tried drawing each image individually on the canvas and then using 
context.getImageData(0, 0, imageWidthOfCut, imageHeightOfCut).data;
to get the array. But that was very slow for 512 images. What you describe however looks faster. I will try it and come back with feedback.

Comment: I would also be interested in the method you mentioned in the end, if you can provide me with some link.

Comment: Actually the middle approach of using the textures as they arrive is probably best because it will make the atlas texture as the images are downloaded which will be less likely freeze the browser where as drawing 512 images into a canvas all at once will probably freeze the browser for a second or 2 or 3 or 4 depending on the power of the machine. Also, I'm not sure why you called `ctx.getImageData`. You can pass a canvas directly to `gl.texImage2D`

Comment: I was referring to my initial approach (see B in first post) where I was trying to create a `THREE.DataTexture` from the image array and load it to the shader. 
Why would the middle approach be faster? Cumulatively you must also call the `ctx.drawImage(img, x * width, y * height);` 512 times and store the result in the canvas.
As for the images, you are right. But this means significant refactoring of my classes to create the Rendering-Context(gl) before and pass it  to the Texture/Image loader :-/.
I didn't need it so far since I was using the `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture` function.

Comment: I didn't say it was faster. It said it's less likely to freeze the browser. Doing one image draw every few ms as they get downloaed means the browser can stay responsive. Doing them all at once in a tight loop means the browser is frozen until done. I doubt it will freeze for that long but better not to freeze at all if possible.